# Making a hidden element clickable in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium

I have the following element:

```
<input type="hidden" data-dojo-attach-point="vn" value="adrija" aria- 
hidden="true">
```

The above element is an element of dropdown and is hidden. The code that I have written is:

```
private WebElement adrija = Driver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='adrija' and @data-dojo-attach-point='vn']"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", adrija);
```

It says it's not able to find the element.

Please help. Thanks. :)

Comment: `By.type()` is not part of the Java Selenium API. Is this a custom extension? Does your code even compile? Please have a read how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Use css selector

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='hidden']"))
```

Or xpath

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='hidden']"))
```

Note : the field has type hidden. You cannot do visible interaction like sendkeys or click as it is invisible

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I also need to click it and also there are more than one value. So I can't only look for type. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: As you are saying it is drop-down, then i m 100% sure this not right element to click. There may be some other element to click. If you add the outer html of drop-down to question, it will be helpful to give you the right answer

Answer (score 0):

Selenium cannot work on the hidden elements. First, you need the click on the button which opens the drop-down menu. Then you do whatever you want. :).

Comment: I have done, what you said, but still its giving me the same problem. I have edited the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("XPATH"));
    element.click();

    WebElement childElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("HidenElementXpath"));
    childElement.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If the hidden element is in a frame, you need to switch to the frame!!!
2. Then try to find the element