# Making a hidden element displayable and clickable in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium

I have the following element:

```
<table class="dijit " data-dojo-attach-point="_buttonNode" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="lbox" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0" id="POS_domain" data-id="domain" widgetid="POS_domain" aria-expanded="false" aria- invalid="false" style="user-select: none;" popupactive="true" aria-owns="POS_domain">
    <tbody role="presentation">
        <tr role="presentation">
            <td class="dijitReset" role="presentation">
                <div class="dijitReset Text" data-dojo-attach-point="container" role="presentation">
                    <span role="option" aria-selected="true" class="dijitLabel ">adrija</span>
                </div>
                <div class="dijitContainer">
                    <input class="dijitInner" value="Χ " type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation">
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" data-dojo-attach-point="vn" value="adrija" hidden="true">
            </td>
            <td class="dijitArrowButtonContainer" data-dojo-attach-point="titleNode" role="presentation">
                <input class="dijitInner" value="▼ " type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The above element is an element of dropdown and is hidden. The code that I have written is:

```
private WebElement domainDropdown = Driver.driver.findElement(By.id("POS_domain"));
domainDropdpwn.click();
private WebElement adrija = Driver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='adrija' and @data-dojo-attach-point='vn']"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", adrija);
```

It says it's not able to find the element.

Please help. Thanks. :)

Comment: I guess it's hidden for the reason. And if it's hidden you should not be able to click it unless you perform some additional actions... or you're simply trying to handle wrong element

Comment: You state that the element is of a dropdown.  Dropdown elements are hidden until the dropdown opens, and even then, not all contents are visible.  Regardless, if the dropdown is defined as a "select" you should process it that way and not try to click the options inside.

Comment: I tried processing but even when it opens, it comes as element not clickable @BillHileman

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML code to your original post.  What I mean is, the additional HTML code surrounding the one line you did show, specifically the dropdown control.

Comment: @Adrija What is your goal  testing or web scrapping or ethical hacking?

Comment: @BillHileman I edited the changes

Comment: @Navarasu The goal is automation testing, thats it. The goal is very much different form the previous question.

Comment: @Navarasu I added everything you asked for :)

Comment: Thanks for the html. Can u add the screenshot of component to with dropdown? It is difficult to understand the component with partial html.

Comment: Try clicking the span, Driver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='adrija']")).click() instead of that input

Comment: @Navarasu I tried, I am getting ' stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document' as an error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a hidden element clickable in selenium java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52934054/making-a-hidden-element-clickable-in-selenium-java)

Comment: Please do not ask the same question twice. Instead edit your original question with additional information to make it more clear.

Comment: @SiKing Please see the previous comments

Comment: Please add screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

The desired `<input>` tag is having the attributes `type="hidden"` and `hidden="true"`, so to `click()` on the element you can use the following solution:

```
//driver being an instance of WebDriver
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//table[@class='dijit ' and @id='POS_domain']"))).click();
WebElement my_adrija = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='adrija' and @data-dojo-attach-point='vn']"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('hidden')", my_adrija)
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('type','text')", my_adrija)
WebElement my_new_adrija = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@value='adrija' and @data-dojo-attach-point='vn']")));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", my_new_adrija);
```

Comment: I am getting this as an error "stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document"

Comment: Updated answer. Let me know the status.

Comment: Updated answer again. Let me know the status.

Comment: Hi @DebanjanB the element is getting visible but its unable to click it. The same error persists.

Comment: Updated answer. Confirm the status please.